# Manifolds with boundaries and vertices

Tags: manifolds

I heard about manifolds with boundaries, but I never heard about manifolds with boundaries and vertices except perhaps in Spivak's book.
Take a solid cube.
It's a 3-dimensional manifold with a boundary and 8 vertices.
So I think manifolds with boundaries and vertices are natural objects of mathematics.
Particularly I'd like to see a proof of Stokes' theorem on these manifolds.
Are there books which treat these manifolds?

Comment: See this post on MO:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12920/stokes-theorem-for-manifolds-with-corners

Comment: @Brett Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Papers, books and articles which treat manifolds with corners and Stokes' theorem on them:

Joyce "On manifolds with corners" arxiv.org/abs/0910.3518.

Partial Differential Equations 1. Foundations and Integral Representations by Friedrich Sauvigny.

John Lee's book "Introduction to smooth manifolds".

Brian Conrad's notes on differential geometry: math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts.html

Ch. XXIII in Lang's Real and Functional Analysis entitled "Stokes' Theorem with Singularities".